Receiving streaming server response chunk by chunk
I have a rest api which streams data in chunks. Each chunk is a list of 100 records.
In javascipt I use fetch API and it receives one chunk at a time.
But I am not able to have same behaviour in python. I have following code:
response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
response.raise_for_status()
response_text = response.text
print(response_text)

I see that response_text contains multiple json lists, while I expect only one list at a time.
What mistake am I making here?

https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#body-content-workflow

"I see that response_text contains multiple json lists, while I expect only one list at a time." - What exactly does this mean? Please show an example of the output, and show exactly how you think it should be different, and why. What is a "chunk", and why do you expect to be able to get one at a time using response.text? In your own words, what do you expect response.text to do, and why?

If you want to know how to do something, please ask how to do that thing - don't present some code and look for debugging help.

In python when you use response.text, it reads the entire response content at once, which is why you're seeing multiple JSON lists. so, to get the same behavior as javascripts fetch function  you should iterate over the response using  response.iter_lines() like this
response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
response.raise_for_status()

for line in response.iter_lines():
    if line:  
        data = json.loads(line)
        print(data)

try using iter_content() if the data isn't newline-delimited
response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
response.raise_for_status()

buffer = ""
for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
    buffer += chunk.decode('utf-8')
    while "\n" in buffer:  
        line, buffer = buffer.split("\n", 1)
        if line:
            data = json.loads(line)
            print(data)


When I use this pattern, for loop is never executed, as if response is empty.

@Mandroid then try using iter_content() if the data isn't newline-delimited.

I will go with using iter_content as the docs
"Iterates over the response data.  When stream=True is set on the
request, this avoids reading the content at once into memory for
large responses.  The chunk size is the number of bytes it should
read into memory.  This is not necessarily the length of each item
returned as decoding can take place.
"
Here is a sample code :
import requests

url = "your_api_endpoint"
response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
response.raise_for_status()

# each chunk of data 
for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
    if chunk:
      
        print(chunk.decode('utf-8'))

OR
import requests
import json

url = "your_api_endpoint"
response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
response.raise_for_status()

# Create an iterator from iter_content
chunks = response.iter_content(chunk_size=None, decode_unicode=True)

buffer = ""

# Use next to fetch one chunk at a time
try:
    while True:
        chunk = next(chunks)
        if chunk:
            buffer += chunk  # Append chunk to buffer
            try:
                # Try to parse the buffer as JSON
                json_list = json.loads(buffer)
                print(json_list)
                buffer = ""  # Clear buffer after successful parsing
            except json.JSONDecodeError:
                # continue accumulating chunks
                continue
except StopIteration:
    print(".....")


